# Question on choice of Coding System of Gödel Numbering

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I am reading this [section](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic_(Leary_and_Kristiansen)/05%3A_Syntactic_Incompleteness__Groundwork/5.07%3A_Godel_Numbering) from the book "A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Christopher Leary and Lars Kristiansen. The authors define the coding system as follows:

The function $\ulcorner \cdot \urcorner$, with domain the collection of finite strings of $\mathcal{L}_{NT}$-symbols and codomain $\mathbb{N}$, is defined as follows:

$$\ulcorner s \urcorner = \begin{cases} \begin{array}{ll} \langle 1, \ulcorner \alpha \urcorner \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: \left( \neg \alpha \right), \: \text{where} \: \alpha \: \text{is an} \: \mathcal{L}_{NT} \text{-formula} \\ \langle 3, \ulcorner \alpha \urcorner, \ulcorner \beta \urcorner \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: \left( \alpha \lor \beta \right), \: \text{where} \: \alpha \: \text{and} \: \beta \: \text{are} \: \mathcal{L}_{NT} \text{-formulas} \\ \langle 5, \ulcorner v_i \urcorner, \ulcorner \alpha \urcorner \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: \left( \forall v_i \right) \left( \alpha \right), \: \text{where} \: \alpha \: \text{is an} \: \mathcal{L}_{NT} \text{-formula} \\ \langle 7, \ulcorner t_1 \urcorner, \ulcorner t_2 \urcorner \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: = t_1 t_2, \: \text{where} \: t_1 \: \text{and} \: t_2 \: \text{are terms} \\ \langle 9 \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: 0 \\ \langle 11, \ulcorner t \urcorner \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: St, \: \text{with} \: t \: \text{a term} \\ \langle 13, \ulcorner t_1 \urcorner, \ulcorner t_2 \urcorner \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: + t_1 t_2, \: \text{where} \: t_1 \: \text{and} \: t_2 \: \text{are terms} \\ \langle 15, \ulcorner t_1 \urcorner, \ulcorner t_2 \urcorner \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: \cdot t_1 t_2, \: \text{where} \: t_1 \: \text{and} \: t_2 \: \text{are terms} \\ \langle 17, \ulcorner t_1 \urcorner, \ulcorner t_2 \urcorner \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: E t_1 t_2, \: \text{where} \: t_1 \: \text{and} \: t_2 \: \text{are terms} \\ \langle 19, \ulcorner t_1 \urcorner, \ulcorner t_2 \urcorner \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is} \: < t_1 t_2, \: \text{where} \: t_1 \: \text{and} \: t_2 \: \text{are terms} \\ \langle 2i \rangle & \text{if} \: s \: \text{is the variable} \: v_i \\ 3 & \text{otherwise.} \end{array} \end{cases}$$

Notice that each symbol is associated with its symbol number, as set out in the table

$$\begin{array}{||c|c||c|c||} \hline \text{Symbol} & \text{Symbol Number} & \text{Symbol} & \text{Symbol Number} \\ \hline \neg & 1 & + & 13 \\ \lor & 3 & \cdot & 15 \\ \forall & 5 & E & 17 \\ = & 7 & < & 19 \\ 0 & 9 & ( & 21 \\ S & 11 & ) & 23 \\ & & v_i & 2i \\ \hline \end{array}$$

---

It's quite evident that this coding system assigns very small formulas like $=00$ very large numbers. In this case, $\ulcorner =00 \urcorner =2^83^{1025}5^{1025}$. Instead using this coding system, we could just code formula $\phi =c_1c_2\ldots c_n$ where each $c_i$ is a symbol (and it must be one of the above as in the table) in the following way:
$$\ulcorner \phi \urcorner = \prod_{i=1}^{n} p_i ^ {\text{value corresponding to } c_i \text{ in the table}}$$
where $p_i$ is the ith prime.

This mapping would also code formulas but would assign smaller formula to (relatively!!) smaller numbers. For instance, $\ulcorner =00 \urcorner = 2^73^95^9$ in my coding system.

**Why did the authors choose their coding system the way they have done? Does it make things easier later? I understand that there would no unique way of doing this. It would be great if I understand why some systems are preferred to others.**

Comment: Because there is no interest in effectively computing the code, but only in defining an algorithm that produces codes. The theorem needs only the existence of the algorithm, not its "results".

Comment: I'm don't really know, but it might be a little easier to prove that the decoding (numbers to formulas) is computable (in whatever sense that needs to be shown) if the coding only uses simple addition and multiplication rather than an enumeration of primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mauro Allegranza commented, unnecessarily large values is *not* a drawback. Meanwhile there is a minor advantage that the given system has over prime factorization coding: namely, it makes the syntactic form of the formula more obvious from its code.

Specifically, suppose I give you a number $n$ and tell you that $n$ is the Godel number of a formula $\varphi$, and ask whether $\varphi$ has the form $(\psi\vee\theta)$ or not. Using prime factorization coding this is a bit tricky, since we need to "locate" the prime corresponding to the outermost logical operation. The coding provided in the text, however, makes this trivial: just ask whether $n$ has the form $\langle 3,a,b\rangle$. This makes things a bit simpler when for example defining "$x$ is (the code for) a proof of the sentence (coded by) $y$."

Comment: You're right. But is it possible to setup the proofs of Incompleteness Theorem using the coding system which I mentioned or would it be really difficult to do this?

Comment: @ashK It's absolutely possible (and I've taught it that way before), but it is more tedious. I don't consider it *really* difficult, though.